# Why Rolle's theorem is giving two roots here?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, derivatives, continuity, rolles-theorem

I am trying to find Number of distinct roots of $$f(x)=x+5\cos x=0$$ in $\left[0, \pi \right]$

we have $f(0)=5 \gt 0$ and $f(\pi)=\pi-5 \lt 0$ so by IVT we have at least one root in $\left[0,  \pi \right]$

Now IVT does not give information on number of roots, So I assumed let $p$ and $q$ are two distinct roots of $f(x)$ in $\left[0, \pi \right]$

Now $$f(p)=f(q)=0$$ Now applying Rolle's Theorem we get

$$f'(c)=0$$ that is

$$1-5 \sin c=0$$

so $$c =\arcsin(0.2)$$ which  $\in$ $\left[0,\pi \right]$

hence My assumption that there are two roots $p$ and $q$ is correct. But Graph shows there is only one root in $\left[0,\pi \right]$

Where I went wrong?

Comment: You're not applying Rolle's theorem, you're applying the converse. Which btw is not valid..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You proved correctly that **if** thare are two roots $p,q\in[0,\pi]$, **then** one of them is smaller that $\arcsin\left(\frac15\right)$, whereas the other one is larger. The doesn't imply that those roots actually exist.

For instance, by the same argument, **if** the equation $x^2=-1$ has two real roots, **then** one of them is positive and the other one is negative. However, those roots do not exist.

Comment: Ok you mean to say that my $c$ may not lie in $(p \:\: q)$

Comment: No. I mean to say that just beacu $f'(c)=0$, you can't deduce from that that $f$ has to have a root.

Comment: Ok clear. But if in case we got $c$ outside the interval, Then can we guarantee that $f(x)=0$ has exactly one root?

Comment: Yes, that would be correct. However, note that $\arcsin\left(\frac15\right)\in\left(0,\frac\pi2\right)$.

Comment: Ok so you mean if $IVT$ is Succesful and $Rolle's$ Theorem fails, Then $f(x)=0$ has exactly one root in given interval $\left[a \:\: b \right]$

Comment: No, I don't mean that, since ROlle's theorem never fails (otherwise, it would not be a theorem). What fails is the reverse implication.